# VBA for capitalizing title slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to use VBA to capitalize each word in the titles of all my PowerPoint slides.

So far this is the code I am using:

```
Sub Capitalize()
    Dim sld As Slide

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
            sld.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.ChangeCase ppCaseTitle
        Next sld
End Sub
```

It's giving me an error by highlighting the "Title" and saying "Method or data member not found"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should learn to use the documentation in the [PowerPoint Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff743835.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Title object is available on the Shapes object, which maps on to the placeholder title for the slide. I would also use the HasTitle property to check if the slide has a title or not.

```
Sub Capitalize()
Dim sld As Slide

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If sld.Shapes.HasTitle Then
        sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.ChangeCase ppCaseTitle
    End If
Next sld
End Sub
```

Comment: @change33 note that the best way to say "thank you so much" on this site, is to tick that checkmark (and, once you get to 15 rep, to vote up).

Answer (score 1):

A `Slide` object doesn't have a `Title` property. You need to look for the `Shape` object that contains the title text.

Iterate the `.Shapes` collection and use its `Name` to know when you've found the one that contains your title (then you can exit the loop).

This assumes you've named the title shape "Title" or something.

```
Dim sld As Slide, shp As Shape
Dim found As Boolean
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.Name = "Title" Then
            found = True
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.ChangeCase ppCaseTitle
        End If
        If found Then Exit For
    Next
    If found Then Exit For
Next
```

Comment: if doing it as an own sob you could directly `Exit Sub` it and skip the whole `found`-part ^^

Comment: @DirkReichel absolutely

Comment: Your code is checking if the name of the shape is 'Title' and that is not the same as the slide title.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without naming the shape as "Title"? Could I just loop through and say capitalize the first letter of each word in shape 1 of each slide?

Comment: I am totally new to VBA so apologies if these are dumb/basic questions

Comment: @ShyamPillai great, I've upvoted your answer. This is pretty much the first time I'm seeing any VBA written specifically for PowerPoint (I've always wondered what one would want to automate with VBA in PowerPoint), and I don't know that object model like the palm of my hand.

Comment: @change33 I wouldn't do that, it assumes shape 1 of each slide contains your title - it's often best to not assume stuff when writing code (that said, my code assumes title shape is named "Title", so...) ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug: From creation of decks to slideshows, you would be surprised at the usage. :-)

Comment: I would recommend never attempting to identify an object based on data that a user can change i.e. via the Selection Pane. The Name property is also localised. In this case, you can iterate the Shapes.Placeholders collectionandn check the PlaceholderFormat.Type property for the title types.